# Serilog - Log full of NUL characters

Tags: serilog

I have a Serilog implementation on a C# application. While debugging in our development environment we like to have the log file open in a text editor, like Notepad++.

As I debug and test I like to clean the log file as I go by deleting all the text and saving the file - while the application is still running.

When the application then next writes a log entry, the log is filled with 'NUL' characters.
It is as through Serilog wants to continue to append the log at the last known index point.

I just want it to write cleanly at the start of the log file again.

Is there is a way to do this?
I don't recall having this outcome when using Log4Net.

[image: Screenshot of log]