# .csv file full of null characters (<0x00>) using serilog and file sink

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous, serilog

We have an app installed on many PC's, that collects some information into .csv each time user clicks (mouse or keyboard button).

The problem is that sometimes a large amount of null characters appears in the mid of .csv file (screenshots are below).
This problem is not global, it appears randomly on some of the pc's.
[image of .csv file with null characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSzKq.png)

This is how the app works:

1. Each time user clicks app invokes "CollectInfo" method

```csharp
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        eventInfoInstanceFromDI.CollectInfo(CancellationSource.Token, otherParams);
    }
);
```

2. This method collects some info about current process, that user are working with. At the end this method invokes "AddRecord" method that adds collected info to .csv file

```csharp
public void CollectInfo(CancellationToken token, otherParams)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                try
                { ... }
                catch
                { ... }
                finally
                {
                    ...
                    ...
                    containerInstanceFromDI.AddRecord(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

3. "AddRecord" and "AggregateData" method:

```charp
///
///Aggregates collected info fields into a string, separated by ';'
///
private string AggregateData(ExportFields data, bool addHeaders, bool addValues, string separator)
        {
            StringBuilder resultingString = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in data.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (_appSettingsOptions.ExcludeFields.Contains(propertyInfo.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) is false)
                {
                    var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(data);
                    MaxLengthAttribute attrMaxLength = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as MaxLengthAttribute;
                    var maxLength = attrMaxLength?.Length ?? _fieldMaxLengthDefault;

                    String valstr = Regex.Replace(val != null ? val.ToString() : "", "[\r\n\t]", "").Replace(";", "|").Trim();
                    valstr = valstr.Length > maxLength ? valstr.Substring(0, maxLength) + " ..." : valstr;
                    resultingString.Append((addHeaders ? propertyInfo.Name + "" : "") + (addValues ? valstr : "") + separator);
                }
            }
            return resultingString.ToString();
        }




        /// 
        ///Adds collected info to .csv file
        ///
        public void AddRecord(ExportFields data, Dictionary<String, Object> extParams = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationConfiguration.FullPathToCsvFile))
                {
                    if (_appSettingsOptions.ExcludeProcs.Contains(data.ProcessName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) is false)
                    {
                        bool append = extParams != null && extParams.ContainsKey("Append") && extParams["Append"].GetType() == typeof(bool) && (bool)extParams["Append"];
                        bool initHeaders = extParams != null && extParams.ContainsKey("InitHeaders") && extParams["InitHeaders"].GetType() == typeof(bool) && (bool)extParams["InitHeaders"];
                        string dataLine = initHeaders ? AggregateData(data, true, false, ";") : AggregateData(data, false, true, ";");

                        _loggerCSV.Information(dataLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String errorMessage = $"Can't add a new record to CSV file. Full Path To Csv File: {ApplicationConfiguration.FullPathToCsvFile}.";

                _loggerMain.Error("{ErrorMessage}. Error in {MethodInClass}. Error: {@Exception}.", errorMessage, nameof(CSVContainer) + " => " + nameof(AddRecord), ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

4. String goes to .csv file

The next screenshot is the end of this invalid string:
[end of the line with null characters in .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhpNn.png)

The string ends with collected info from another process (string starts with "Word" process info, ends with "Excel"), that means other strings between these two are lost in this pile of null chars.

What's the reason of such behavior and how to fix\avoid this problem?

I've tried asking this question in serilog's git. They answered that this might be some low level problem or in-memory problem.

Same question from git: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1726

Similar problem from stack: [Serilog - Log full of NUL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922486/serilog-log-full-of-nul-characters)

Comment: Every time the user clicks, a new task is spawned to write the current data to a file.  I presume it's the same file for each task?  It sounds like you are trying to write to the same file by multiple threads, and your simple `lock` isn't working (which I think it correct behaviour for tasks).

Comment: @Neil, thanks for your answer. Yes, it is the same file being written by multiple `Tasks`. I thought  that `lock` would resolve the problem with writing `Data` from these tasks in the order they came in. Is there any option to achieve this result the right way, if the `lock` doesn't work here?

Comment: I would be tempted to have each task write to their own file, and then have 1 task that monitors the log folder and combines them sequentially into 1 file, and then delete the original.